# Почeму при использовании класса FaceDetection функция pose() возвращает 0.0?

Tags: java, android

При распозновании лица на фотографии, нужно учитывать угол поворота лица, для этого я использую функцию `pose()`, которой передаем параметр `int euler`, и как я понимаю, что `pose()` должна возвратить углы поворота по оси X,Y и Z.
Но в моем примере она возвращает 0.0, даже когда фотография сделана в профиль.

**Вот код**

```
 if (facesFound > 0) {
            for (int index = 0; index < facesFound; ++index) {
                //get distance between eyes
                faces[index].getMidPoint(midPoint);
                eyeDistance = faces[index].eyesDistance();

                System.out.println("setFace(): face " + index + ": confidence = " + faces[index].confidence()
                        + ", eyes distance = " + faces[index].eyesDistance()
                        + ", pose = (" + faces[index].pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_X) + ","
                        + faces[index].pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Y) + ","
                        + faces[index].pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Z) + ")"
                        + ", eyes midpoint = (" + midPoint.x + "," + midPoint.y + ")");

                // 2 примера, которые мы видим в Log

                //  setFace(): face 0: confidence = 0.525987, eyes distance = 69.65625, pose = (0.0,0.0,0.0), eyes midpoint = (125.421875,132.375)
                // setFace(): face 0: confidence = 0.51218677, eyes distance = 56.59375, pose = (0.0,0.0,0.0), eyes midpoint = (147.14063,124.5

                if (faces[index].confidence() < 1f
                        && faces[index].pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_X) < 3
                        && faces[index].pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Y) < 3
                        && faces[index].pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Z) < 3) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Good photo for face detection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // this method draw rect around face
                    canvas.drawRect((int) midPoint.x - eyeDistance,
                            (int) midPoint.y - eyeDistance,
                            (int) midPoint.x + eyeDistance,
                            (int) midPoint.y + eyeDistance, drawPaint);

                } else if (faces[index].confidence() > 1f && faces[index].pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_X) > 3
                        && faces[index].pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Y) > 3
                        && faces[index].pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Z) > 3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "confidence more 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // if don't found face, you will see Toast
        } else if (facesFound == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No face!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: На англоязычном stackoverflow.com пишут, что pose всегда возвращает 0.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960563/android-facedetector-face-euler-angles-are-0-all-the-time - такая вот особенность реализации.